# not able to edit sharepoint page in any browser

Tags: edit

I am not able to edit my pages in sharepoint 2013 in any browsers(IE, Chrome,Mozila,Safari). On clickin edit button it is showing me blank page.

Answer (score 1):

When the pages are already checked out to someone else you cannot see the ribbon at the top of the page.

Let me know if your case is different.

Answer (score 1):

Incase you are having content editor webparts and in which it has some javascript, you may see these type of issues.

Recommended way is have the Javascript or jQuery code in a txt file and link it to the CE Webpart.

Let me know if this doesnt suffice your problem